# How to add a certificate to the root trusted certificate but no alert window in C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a project which is packaging the help file to VS 2010. I look for some informations, and I known steps of packaging. As follows:

1. Composited the help file with the extension name called ".cab"
2. Constructed a certificate file for current user
3. Install the certificate to the system.
4. Signed the .cab file with the certificate.
5. Install .cab file to VS2010 with help viewer.

I coded an application to realized steps as above. It was failed in step 4 after I installed the certificate as personal certificate. I found that it would be ok when I installed the certificate in root trusted certificate. But when I'm installing the certificate as a root trusted certificate, did the confirm window pop up!

I wana install the root trusted certificate with no confirm window in coding C# console application. What shoud I do?

Comment: You are asking how to get around the security that certificates provide. There is no way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, to do what you want you need to bypass the MS CAPI interface and add your certificate + mark it as trusted for code-signing (you will need to correctly build the certificates involved as well). For help with that you must reach out to the dark side. Perhaps ask Microsoft for some help with this via email - let us know how it turns out ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help, I had put the question to MSDN Furm about Visual C# General, and got some replies about it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/563a7a01-1aba-486b-997e-3db918991edd/